# How do I interpret the return from posix_ipc::MessageQueue::receive()?

Tags: python, posix, message-queue

I'm using Philip Semanchunk's posix_ipc python module to read from a posix message queue.  A C++ program I've written populates the queue with a struct containing the data.  My python program successfully reads the message off the queue but I'm not sure what to do with the resulting message.

doing a `print msg` just prints out an empty string but I know msg has something in it.

I want to be able to read the members of the struct but I'm assuming I need to do something maybe with the struct module to marshal this message into something readable?  Has anyone done anything like this?

I've read through his documentation and demos, but he is using simple types and I haven't found any examples where the source is a C struct.  Google hasn't been any help either.

Also, I'm restricted to using Python 2.3.  Thanks!

Comment: Try calling dir(msg) to see what attributes etc. you have to play with.

Comment: good suggestion!  Looks like I'm dealing with a str of escaped hex values.  Now where have I seen this before... I think the struct module should take care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Python struct module.

`struct::unpack()` will translate the hex string from `MessageQueue::receive()` into a tuple of strings